# Using an object of separate class in a class constructor

Tags: c++, xcode, object, constructor, member

What's the proper way to set up the following constructor for SquareValue?
I'm getting the following Error:

"constructor for SquareValue must explicitly initialize the member "square" which does not have a default constructor"

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

using std::cout;
using std::endl;
using std::string;

class Square {

public:
int X, Y;

Square(int x_val, int y_val) {
    X = x_val;
    Y = y_val;
}

};


class SquareValue {

public:

Square square;
int value;

SquareValue(Square current_square, int square_value) {
    square = current_square;
    value = square_value;
}
};
```

I had planned on passing the Square() constructor into the SquareValue constructor.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When you don't initialize an object using the list initialization syntax in the constructor, the default constructor is used:

```
SquareValue(Square current_square, int square_value) {
    square = current_square;
    value = square_value;
}
```

is equivalent to:

```
SquareValue(Square current_square, int square_value) : square() {
    square = current_square;
    value = square_value;
}
```

`square()` is a problem since `Square` does not have a default constructor.

Use:

```
SquareValue(Square current_square, int square_value) :
   square(current_square), value(square_value) {}
```

Comment: Alternatively change the Square constructor to `Square(int x_val = 0, int y_val = 0)` so that it can be default-constructed.

Comment: Thanks, I had done some troubleshooting with initialization syntax but didn't seem to catch on.